# Include an image in itemize in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize, overlays

I have to do a presentation with `beamer`. In a frame I want to insert an image as a object in `itemize`, so in the first step is only visible the writings, while in the second step the image appears. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Key Variables in the \textit{Bubble} Phenomena}
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\item[]<1-> The mean value $\bar{\beta}_{i,t}$ of the intensity parameter is crucial for the development of the synchronization phase, hence it also affects the production volume:
%\vspace{0.1cm}
\begin{center}
\item[]<2-> {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{gdp_betaC}}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{2cm}
\end{frame}
```

I don't know why, but if I use `itemize` with different writings as steps the code works, but if I include the image in the second step, the latter appears together with the first one.

Comment: Your document misses an `\end{document}` statement ;-)

Comment: ok, it's a misprint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overlay specification for `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Key Variables in the \textit{Bubble} Phenomena}
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\item[] The mean value $\bar{\beta}_{i,t}$ of the intensity parameter is crucial for the development of the synchronization phase, hence it also affects the production volume:
\begin{center}
\item[] \includegraphics<2->[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the text to "jump" from slide to slide, use `overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Key Variables in the \textit{Bubble} Phenomena}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\item[] The mean value $\bar{\beta}_{i,t}$ of the intensity parameter is crucial for the development of the synchronization phase, hence it also affects the production volume:
\begin{center}
\item[] \includegraphics<2->[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's not clear to me why you are killing the itemize labels with `\item[]`.